# Name error while rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to render a sub form in my main form and i tried to render it in the main form

this issue has relation with three models

```
Class PrdItem model< ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :prd_allisland_flat_delivery, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :prd_item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for   :prd_allisland_flat_delivery, allow_destroy: true

  has_many :prd_province_vise_deliveries,  dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :prd_item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for   :prd_province_vise_deliveries, allow_destroy: true
end


Class PrdAllislandFlatDelivery < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :prd_item
end

Class PrdProvincevisedelivery < ActiveRecord::Base      
  belongs_to :prd_item
end
```

In `prd_item/new.html.erb`  the `_form.html.erb` is rendered

in that `_form.html.erb`
 i wrote this code fragment

```
<%=  p.fields_for :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries  do |i| %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => p})%>
<% end %>
```

this is a fragment of that form partial

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
    </div>
```

that gives me

undefined method

> `delivery_period' for #

error

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: @Anand   undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0xb85fae0>:0xf156978>   this is the error i added a picture couldn't you see

Comment: `<%= render partial:  'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', locals: { f: f} %>` try this

Comment: did this resolve your error?

Comment: Gives the same error

Comment: can you share code of main form ?

Comment: It is so huge to share

Comment: i think you are rendering partial out of main form scope? check it if this line of code in between main form starting and ending?

Comment: Can you please paste your form tag code from you main form ?

Comment: <%= form_for(@item) do |p| %>                                                                <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:p => p})%>  and in this form partial iam rendering                                                                                                 <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => f})%>      is it clear?

Comment: @pasM  show you main form.

Comment: what if it is too huge for sharing

Comment: try ```<%= render 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', f: p %>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `_form.html.erb`

```
<%=  p.fields_for :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries  do |i| %>
  <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => i})%>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= f.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
```

Comment: I tried this but the sub form details which i want to submit is not for the table related to the main form it is for another table.

Comment: Therefore i edited the code snippet like this                                                            <%=  p.fields_for :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries  do |i| %>
                                                                                                               <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => p})%>
<% end %>

Comment: but this gave me  NoMethodError

Comment: kindly share your code , so that i can help you in right way.

Comment: check the answer render `prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field` is in local scope with local variable `i` so it should be `:locals => {:f => i}`

Comment: @pasM welcome, let me know if you need any other guidance. :)

Comment: sure i will  ask for any clarifications

Comment: can you refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197975/parameters-are-in-the-console-but-not-passing-to-the-database

Comment: @pasM Thanks for your concern, let me see if i can find solution for your new problem.

Comment: if so can you respond quick because im in a little hurry

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412388/how-can-i-access-nested-params-in-controller-since-it-gives-me-undefined-method