# parameters are in the console but not passing to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in Main form

```
 <%=  p.fields_for :prd_allisland_flat_deliveries  do |i| %>

   <%= render(:partial => 'prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field', :locals => {:f => i})%>
 <% end %>
```

in the prd_allisland_flat_delivery_field  form partial

```
   <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :delivery_period %>
          </div>



            <div class="col-md-4">


     <%= f.text_field(:delivery_period, {placeholder: '0', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 25px">
          <div class="col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :delivery_rate %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.text_field(:delivery_rate, {placeholder: 'Rs. 0.00', class: 'form-control input_border input_field_text_align_right'})%>
          </div>

        </div>
```

in prd_item controller

**def new

```
@item = PrdItem.new

@item.build_prd_allisland_flat_delivery
```

end**

after writing this the create method

**

```
if @item.save

  if @item.delivery_type == 1

     @all_island_flat = PrdAllislandFlatDelivery.new(item_params[:prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes])
    @all_island_flat.save
  end
```

end**

the item_params

def item_params

```
    params.require(:prd_item).permit(:item_name, :brand, :item_no, :short_description, :long_description, :prd_type_id, :usr_vendor_property_id, :price,:base_price, :price_discount, :percentage_discount, :stock_count, :availability, :tags, :remove_image, :delivery_type , :min_stock_count,

                                 prd_item_images_attributes: [:id, :image, :description, :link, :_destroy ],

                                 prd_temp_variation_stores_attributes: [:id, :product_variations, :variation_items, :_destroy],
                                 prd_temp_compound_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
                                 prd_temp_spec_stores_attributes:[:id,:compound, :compound_item, :_destroy],
                                 prd_allisland_flat_deliveries_attributes: [:id,:delivery_period,:delivery_rate],
                                 prd_province_vise_deliveries_attributes: [:id , :province_name , :delivery_rate, :delivery_period]

                                 )
```

end

the rails consoler gets the attributes for the  prd_allisland_flat_deliveries but the prd_all_island_flat_deliveries fill with null values

Answer (score 0):

Is that your full create method? If so you need to understand that every request is separate from others, the create request doesn't know what happened in the new request.

In your create method you need to build your basic object, then update the object from the params.

```
def create
  @item = PrdItem.new
  @item.update(item_params)
  if @item.save ...
```

Comment: this is not the full create method i posted only the relavant partials in my create method  i created the object as you have done here

Comment: no this is not the full create method  in my create method i have creates the item object as you have done here